# ¿Cómo hago para que mi navbar no se esconda al scrollear para abajo?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Estoy haciendo un sitio web para un restaurante, pero tengo un problema con el navbar al scrollear para abajo. Le agregué un efecto que le cambia el color al srcollear hacia abajo. El problema es que el navbar se esconde y vuelve a aparecer completamente cuando scrolleo hacia arriba.
Adjunto imágenes.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi código hasta acá:

**HTML:**

```
<nav class="navbar fixed-top navbar-expand-lg fuentes-personalizadas" id="navScroll">
```

**CSS:**

```
.fuentes-personalizadas {
    background: rgba(19, 15, 15, 0) !important;
    color: white;
}

.fuentes-personalizadas li {
    font-weight: bold;
}

.fuentes-personalizadas a {
    color: white;
}

.fuentes-personalizadas a:hover {
    color: tomato
}

.fuentes-personalizadas-scroll {
    background: white !important;
    color: black;
}

.fuentes-personalizadas-scroll li {
    font-weight: bold;
}

.fuentes-personalizadas-scroll a {
    color: black;
}

.fuentes-personalizadas-scroll a:hover {
    color: red;
}
```

**JS:**

```
function scrollEffect(pxPantalla) {
    window.addEventListener("scroll", () => {
        let scroll = document.documentElement.scrollTop;
        let bgChange = document.getElementById("navScroll");
        let marcoHamburg = document.getElementById("marcoHamburg");
        let iconoHamburg = document.getElementById("iconoHamburg");

        if (scroll > pxPantalla) {
            bgChange.className = "navbar fixed-top navbar-expand-lg fuentes-personalizadas-scroll";
            marcoHamburg.className = "navbar-toggler text-dark";
            iconoHamburg.className = "fas fa-bars text-dark";
        } else {
            bgChange.className = "navbar fixed-top navbar-expand-lg fuentes-personalizadas";
            marcoHamburg.className = "navbar-toggler text-light";
            iconoHamburg.className = "fas fa-bars text-light";
        }
    })
}

scrollEffect(20);
```

Comment: Qué has intentado hasta ahora?

Comment: Hasta hora intenté solucionarlo agregándole margin top y padding top al navbar, pero se ve muy raro, ya que cuando scrolleo hacia arriba, la configuración se mantiene.

Comment: Excelente, [edita tu pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/425584/edit) y añade el código que tienes para que puedas recibir ayuda óptima

Comment: @anythingg agregado el código a la pregunta. Gracias

Answer (score 0):

prepare este código, espero te ayude

el HTML es sencillo y solo tiene declarado los elementos y sus clases. En el CSS es donde se deja fijo el navBar en el tope y el contenido del sitio esta separado en 60px del tope para que no se encuentre con el navBar.

la clase alto solo fue para tener espacio para hacer scroll.

HTML

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-light bg-light">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
</nav>


<div class="contenido">
  <p class="alto">
    <label>texto de prueba</label><br>
    <label>texto de prueba</label><br>
    <label>texto de prueba</label><br>
    <label>texto de prueba</label><br>
  </p>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.navbar{
  position: fixed !important;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.contenido{
  margin-top: 60px;
}

.alto{
  height: 600px;
}
```

te dejo el link para que lo veas funcionando
https://jsfiddle.net/naglfar_jv/jkevoLm0/4/

Comment: Muchísimas gracias por tu ayuda José!